# VBA - Calling a SUB in an Access file from Excel with Parameters

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to call a subroutine from the Access file "Hey.accdb" using the Excel file "Hoy.xlsm".  The subroutine's name is "HelloWorld" with parameter "Para01" which is a string.

### Can somebody help me on how I could achieve this?

Here's my coding in the Excel file which does not work:

```
Sub RunSubinAccesswithPara()

'Open Access file
Set Db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        Db.OpenCurrentDatabase "D:\Database1\Hey.accdb"
        Db.Visible = True
        Db.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
        Db.Execute "HelloWorld('Y')"

End Sub
```

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to check: you have the Access reference enabled? What exactly is not working? What error message etc? Are you using quotes correctly in your parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Application.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-run-method-access) method like so:

```
DB.Run "HelloWorld", "Y"
```